# Restrict deleting documents via pouchdb

Tags: couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am using pouchdb with sync gateway to sync documents from Couchbase to the browser.

Using pouchdb inspector the user can make changes to these documents.

So, my question is, is there a way that we can stop user from modifying the document via pouchdb inspector?

Also, even if the user modifies the document via pouchdb inspector, is there a way that I can stop this updated document to be synced back to the Couchbase server?

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: What does the couchbase or pouchdb documentation say about this. Maybe some close matches, so others can more easily help you with answers?

Comment: Have posted this on Couchbase forums and those guys say "they don't know anything about PouchDB inspector (and how you'd prevent updates to the local database)". By setting up roles, channels and access to the documents this can be achieved, however not sure if this works with pouchdb inspector.

Comment: So PouchDB inspector users might help. That is not me, but maybe others can jump in ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer answer: The user is the "admin" of their local data in a web browser. They have absolute power over the pouch, and you can't take it away.

Validation functions might help you out though.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html
or
http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/validation.html

Your function should look for _delete === true on the document or something similar and throw({forbidden : message}).

You can add these to the PouchDB. Unfortunately the user could just delete the validation document, then delete the other documents.

If you added it to the CouchDB, it wouldn't prevent users from messing with the pouch, but the deletions wouldn't sync to the couch.